# How to dynamically adjust QLabel size in a QGridLayout - Qt Creator

Tags: xml, qt, layout, qt-creator, qlabel

I have a grid layout shown below containing 3 QLabel objects that are used to display 3 seperate video streams. Some streams can be toggled off and I want the display to automatically resize within the layout to the maximum size.

[image: layout]
When using two adjacent QLabels (red & blue alone) I was able to do this by using setVisible(false) on one label, and the other label would resize to fill the layout area. But adding a third label object underneath in the following layout has broken this although i'm not sure why.

Here is 2 'streams' activated just **using two adjacent qlabels** in a gridlayout (Just testing with webcam, 2nd display has no video yet)

[image: twostream]
and then after calling label2->setVisible(false)

[image: 1stream]
This is the result I want when using 3 labels. When I try this and set label 2 and 3's visibility off, this is what I get:

[image: bad1stream]
The gridlayout containing the qlabels is using a setFixedSize constraint, and each qlabel is using a preferred sizing policy for horizontal and vertical. You can see that the vertical resizing works as it should but not the horizontal. How can I adjust the label to correctly resize horizontally?

the full style sheet for the ui can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/vJUkMGT8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work with the `QGridLayout` because it it supposed to be more like a table. Same number of rows and columns. If you are going to have those three streams you can use `QHorizontalLayout` for the top two objects and put it with the third object into a `QVerticalLayout`.

The problem is when you close second stream (hide it). Actually you should hide third `QLabel` and play third stream in the second `QLabel`.

It is quite special layout which you should maybe inherit and write your own, especially when you are going to have more streams than three.

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem using a layout within a vertical layout as you suggested.